Xbox Controller Connected But Not Detected in Linux
My Xbox controller with fully updated firmware is connected via Bluetooth as confirmed by a solid white light on the controller, and the system shows as connected:

Further more, xpadneo is installed as described at https://github.com/atar-axis/xpadneo
But, when I try to use the controller or test it with https://gamepadtest.com/, the controller is still not "detected".
What else do I need to do to get the controller to be detected?

sudo -s  Then we disable a bluetooth parameter. echo 'Y' > /sys/module/bluetooth/parameters/disable_ertm Do not worry it is only for your the current session, for testing. After a reboot it is gone.

What does that do?

It disables a part from L2CAP protocoll https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth  as I wrote it is only for current boot so not destructive.

Even though the controller's light is solid white, try pushing the lit-up Xbox button once. Do not hold it down or it will shut off the controller.
Although this behavior is different than Windows, I believe this is what activates xpadneo to begin allowing it to be detected as a controller to the rest of the system.
